# Lots of HTML canvasses or one big one?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-animation

I'm planning an interface to show lots of little widgets (drawn on a `<canvas>`), which may move around (for example in a list that gets sorted different ways with jQuery). The number of widgets may be anywhere between 10 and 100.

I could do this with one big canvas and just paint lots of widgets in the correct place. Or I could have lots of `<canvas>`ses in `<li>`s. Are canvasses light-weight enough for this kind of thing? Is there a compelling performance reason to chose one or the other?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please give constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something similar 3 years ago to represent [BPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_management). I Implemented it with `<canvas>` (I built a lib on top of both canvas and VML - for IE - ) , and I choose the second option u proposed.

The problem with canvas is that if you have lots of interactions (click on a particular element, move it etc), then each time you have to repaint everything (and this, for a large canvas full of elements, isn't the best in terms of performance). I preferred to represent X placeholders (each placeholder is a div containing a canvas), and I noticed performance was better and obviously DOM events (attached to canvas' container) were lot easier to manage.

Another way to implement this kind of interactive stuff could be by using `SVG` (and by now, I'd prefer this), through [raphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) for example. For animations and 2d representation without interaction, I'd use `<canvas>`.

Comment: +1 for the personal experience. Also, wow, did canvas exist 3 years ago? I bet finding documentation was quite a task :)

Comment: Thanks for +1 :) .. and, Yes, there was a pretty good mozilla doc about canvas..And for example google excanvas was already present :)

Comment: I have an "old" Sitepoint book from 07 called The Art and Science of Javascript that has a chapter on Canvas. I remember I completely ignored that chapter at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that performance goes WAAAAAYYYYYY down for a canvas with a height greater than 600px.  So you might want to work around that.  Looking for reference now...

Comment: Interesting! Hope you can find it